# Regular expression for CSS class names

Tags: php, css, regex

I'm trying to create a function in PHP which would go through CSS and JS files, and replacing class names and IDs (but not direct HTML elements or the CSS properties within) in CSS selectors without disrupting the other content. However, of all the dumb luck in the world, I am hopeless when it comes to regular expressions.

I have two arrays, one which has the "original" words, and one that has the words I want to convert it to.

```
$array1 = array("ul", "text", "border");
$array2 = array("bar", "foo", "far");

$str = magic($str, $array1, $array2);
```

And this magical function would change the following CSS file

```
#test-text ul {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ul-border span {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
#text.niceborder {
    border-color: #ccc;
}
```

into

```
#test-foo ul {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.bar-far span {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
#foo.nicefar {
    border-color: #ccc;
}
```

I'm hoping the same function could be used to do the same thing for jQuery selectors in JS, but if I get the basic logic behind finding appropriate selectors and applying the arrays only for . and # segments, I think I can make a `$()` adaptation on my own ;)

Thank you kindly

Comment: This CSS must be huge for it to be easier to write a tool than just to replace the classes one by one.

Comment: You mean I should replace class names manually? The content of $array2 depends on user input, so I need to change the class names on the fly.

Comment: How many items would be in this array? Is it OK to run preg_replace multiple times?

Comment: What's the problem that you are trying to solve? Could you use templates for your css files?

Comment: It's okay for the conversion to be heavy, because the resulting file is cached. So however many preg_replaces it takes, it's fine

Comment: I mean I don't understand what your problem is and what you're trying to achieve. There must be a better way than this, but we need to know your goals to find it.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is that a page contains a CSS file and jQuery JS that is specific to the user and various items connected to the user, and I need to "uniquefy" the class names and IDs so it doesn't affect the rest of the page (which can also contain items connected to different users, so otherwise a clash is likely).

Comment: Why not put clear placeholders in your CSS (such as `$bar`), so that you don't have to worry about conflicts with CSS property names, allowing you to do a basic replacement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you need it, but I think this is the function you want:

```
<?php

/**
 * Replaces all occurences in a CSS class or ID name with the provided replacement.
 * 
 * @param string $subject
 * @param array $search
 * @param array $replace
 * @return string 
 */
function replaceNames($subject, $search, $replace)
{
    // First generate all search regular expressions
    $searchRegexpressions = array_map(function($s)
    {
        return '/([\#\.][a-z0-9\-_]*)(' . preg_quote($s) . ')/i';
    }, $search);
    // Now all associated replacement expressions
    $replaceRegexpressions = array_map(function($r)
    {
        return '$1' . $r;
    }, $replace);

    do {
        // Now do the replacements as often as necessary to replace every occurence.
        $subject = preg_replace($searchRegexpressions, $replaceRegexpressions, $subject, -1, $count);
    } while ($count > 0);

    return $subject;
}
?>
```

To explain the regular expression:

```
/([\#\.][a-z0-9\-_]*)(' . preg_quote($s) . ')/i
```

1. It has to start with either # or .
2. A letter, number or - _ can follow as many times as they want (*). (If you have funkier class names you might have to add characters.)
3. The string in question.

Also: I have used anonymous functions. If you are not using PHP 5.3.0+ you have to actually create the two mapping functions, and use: `array_map(mySearchRegexFuncion, $search);` instead.

Comment: Awesome! Works like the magic that I wanted, thank you so much! :)

Comment: I started adding the items into the array, and everything was going smooth until I hit the 61st value in the arrays, at which point the function starts outputting blanks (values 1-60 still convert fine). Is it a problem with the code or my configuration? I had to move the functions separate, because I'm running PHP 5.2.8

Comment: Mh.. it might be possible that PHP is having problem with the size of the string. Do you get the string from a file? In that case you could do it line / line.

Comment: Makes sense, since the file is some 3500 lines... alright, I'll take it line-by-line. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 0):

I struggle to find a reason what you are trying to do would ever be a good idea.  If you are looking to just change a bunch of styles based off some setting or PHP based logic, just use PHP to generate a single class name, that can then be used to generate overriding CSS rules.

Like so:

```
<?php
  $a = "my-a-style";
  $b = "my-b-style";
  $parentClass = someLogicalFunction() ? $a : $b;
?>
<div class="<?php echo $parentClass; ?>">
  <div id="test">
    <ul>
      <li><span>Some Stuff</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you can just create separate css rules:

```
.my-a-style #test {}
.my-b-style #test {}
```

Comment: That's a pretty good solution for my initial problem. However, I was also looking forward to using the same code to obfuscate and shorten my class names for performance reasons. So .main-general-float-wrapper-spacer becomes .m-g-f-w-s

Comment: @Emphram: Why would you _ever_ have such a long class name? `.main-general-float-wrapper-spacer` is ridiculous. You realise you can have multiple classes on one element, right?

Comment: You can, but not if you want to support IE6.

Comment: IE6 *DOES* support multiple classes, it just doesn't support selecting by multiple classes.